# Is a sequence convergent and if so what is the sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

The sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+2)} $$
Ive made it into partial fractions which gives $\frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3}$
But im unsure how to tell if this now converges as obviously as $n\rightarrow\infty$ the sequence will be 0 so im guessing it does converge, do i need to split the fractions further?

also for the same summation 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-2} + 7 \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$$

Comment: For the second sum, try the formula for geometric series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between being a convergent *sequence,* and being a convergent *series* (which is a sequence of partial sums).

So we can define a sequence as $\{a_n\} = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$, where $a_n$ is the general term of the sequence. And the corresponding series (which is a sequence of partial sums) is usually given as $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n + \cdots$.

A sequence may very well converge, but that doesn't mean the corresponding series converges. All we know is that if the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the term of a sequence **does not** approach zero, then the corresponding series diverges. But the converse is not necessarily true.

---

For your first summation/series, note that the terms of your rewrite nearly all cancel out: expand it for some initial values (writing as a sum), $n = 1, 2, \cdots$ to get a feel for what's happening.

For your second series, use the formula for a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).
$$\left(\dfrac 13\right)^{n-2} + 7\left(\dfrac 14\right)^{n/2} = \left(\dfrac 13 \right)^{n - 2} + 7\left(\dfrac 12\right)^n$$

Comment: Just curious but could you use the Comparison Test to prove this converges?

Comment: Sure, absolutely, @Zhoe!

Comment: Oh ok, thought I was wrong because intuitively that was my first thought but everyone was using partial sums...Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Construct the seq. of partial sums
$$ s_n = \sum_{1}^{n}(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3})=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n+3}. $$

Now, just take the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \large(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3}\large)=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\dots +\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n+3}$$

Now, Question reduces to a simple Question :

> where does $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n+3}$ go when $n\rightarrow \infty$.

even before Doing that, yous should convince yourself that :

> $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\large(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\large)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \large(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3}\large)$

Comment: @Cameron : Thank you for the edit...

Comment: No problem at all.